# Права доступа для получения списка сообщений со стены

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Кто знаком с API вконтакте? Если некоторый пользователь не авторизован в приложении, но при этом у него открыт доступ к стене для всех пользователей, приложение сможет получить список сообщений с его стены с помощью метода wall.get?

Comment: Судя по [документации](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=wall.get), ваше приложение без проблем cможет прочитать записи со стены любого пользователя (если открыты, конечно), если у него есть права доступа с кодом 8192.  Но я не уверен в деталях.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вашего приложения должны быть права для работы со стеной, и тогда оно сможет читать записи с открытой стены любого другого пользователя точно так же, как это бы делал некий пользователь через веб-интерфейс.

Приложение должно получить права для работы со стеной, обозначаемые либо битовой маской 8192 (13-й бит), либо [в текстовом виде](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) при авторизации [по OAuth 2.0](http://vk.com/developers.php?oid=-1&p=%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9), "wall".

Расчитывать на получение этого права теперь могут только Standalone приложения.